# Spring Cloud Gateway — Route Refreshing via Schedule

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config, spring-cloud-gateway

I have a Spring-Cloud-Gateway app (V. Finchley.SR1) and need the routing config to be externalized and refreshable.  I'm currently able to configure the Gateway to pull config from a Cloud-Config app and refresh the routes by hitting the /actuator/refresh endpoint on the cloud app.  However, I'd like to configure the route refresh to be automatic via a schedule rather than requiring a client to POST to /actuator/refresh.  How can this be achieved?

Comment: You could use `@Scheduled` and `ContextRefresher.refresh()`

Comment: @spencergibb thank you for the working suggestion.  Is there a way to specify what aspects of the context (i.e what files) are eligible for refresh this way?  Or is it all-or-nothing?  And in a gateway app, how would calling the `refresh()` method impact the processing of current requests (would it block requests?)

Comment: @acidnbass Maybe this helps you - https://stackoverflow.com/a/54259429/979772