# HikariCP restart with Spring Cloud Config

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, hikaricp, spring-cloud-config

I have recently configured my application to use Spring Cloud Config with Github as a configuration repository.

> - Spring Boot - 2.1.1.RELEASE
> - Spring Cloud Dependencies - Greenwich.RC2

My application is using pretty much everything out of the box. I have just configured the database in `application.yml` and I have HikariCP autoconfigurations doing the magic in the background.

I am refreshing my applications using this job that calls `refresh()` method on the [RefreshEndpoint](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-commons/blob/master/spring-cloud-context/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/endpoint/RefreshEndpoint.java).

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.cloud.endpoint.RefreshEndpoint;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.EnableScheduling;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Scheduled;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@EnableScheduling
@Component
public class ConfigRefreshJob {

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ConfigRefreshJob.class);

    private static final int ONE_MINUTE = 60 * 1000;

    private final RefreshEndpoint refreshEndpoint;

    @Autowired
    public ConfigRefreshJob(final RefreshEndpoint refreshEndpoint) {
        this.refreshEndpoint = refreshEndpoint;
    }

    @Scheduled(fixedDelay = ONE_MINUTE)
    public void refreshConfigs() {
        LOG.info("Refreshing Configurations - {}", refreshEndpoint.refresh());
    }
}
```

Everything seems be working good, but I see following logs every time I refresh the configurations. These logs say HikariCP pool is shutdown and started everytime I refresh.

```
2019-01-16 18:54:55.817  INFO 14 --- [taskScheduler-9] o.s.b.SpringApplication       : Started application in 0.155 seconds (JVM running for 144.646)
2019-01-16 18:54:55.828  INFO 14 --- [taskScheduler-9] c.z.h.HikariDataSource        : HikariPool-1555 - Shutdown initiated...
2019-01-16 18:54:55.828  INFO 14 --- [taskScheduler-9] c.z.h.HikariDataSource        : HikariPool-1555 - Shutdown completed.
2019-01-16 18:54:55.828  INFO 14 --- [taskScheduler-9] c.d.ConfigRefreshJob          : Refreshing Configurations - []
2019-01-16 18:55:03.094  INFO 14 --- [  XNIO-1 task-5] c.z.h.HikariDataSource        : HikariPool-1556 - Starting...
2019-01-16 18:55:03.123  INFO 14 --- [  XNIO-1 task-5] c.z.h.HikariDataSource        : HikariPool-1556 - Start completed.
```

If I look at the times of these logs, it takes around 8 seconds for the HikariCP to be configured again.

I haven't found any issues in my application as of now since the load on the application is not that much right now, but here are couple of questions that I have.

> 1. Does this restart of HikariCP cause issues with the load to the application is increased?
> 2. If the restarting can cause issues, is there a way to not refresh the HikariCP?

Comment: What version are you using?

Comment: You can try to set `spring.cloud.refresh.refreshables` to an empty set.

Comment: @spencergibb I updated the question with spring version. I am using latest `Spring Boot 2.1.1.RELEASE` and `Spring Cloud Depencies Greenwich.RC2`.

Comment: @spencergibb Can you point me to the documentation for this? I don't seem to find it [documented here](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-commons/multi/multi__spring_cloud_context_application_context_services.html#refresh-scope)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HikariCP is made refreshable by default because a change made to it that seals the configuration once the pool is started.

So disable this, set `spring.cloud.refresh.refreshable` to an empty set.

Here is the example to configure in yaml

```
spring:
  cloud:
    refresh:
      refreshable:
      - com.example.app.config.ConfigProperties
```

where `ConfigProperties` is the class annotated with `@RefreshScope`.

Comment: It would be really helpful if there is some documentation around to know how this property can be used.

Comment: @spencergibb Name of the property is wrong, it's `spring.cloud.refresh.refreshable`, not `refreshables`. I used your solution and it didn't work until I noticed that although field is called `refreshables`, the setter is called `setRefreshable`. See `org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.RefreshAutoConfiguration`

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me (spring-boot-**2.2.7.RELEASE**, spring-cloud-**Hoxton.SR4**)

```
spring.cloud.refresh.extra-refreshable=com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
```